# nth-child() pseudo class on <a> tags

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've been creating a new header design for my site and all but one issue is resolved. For some reason, when i try using the `nth-child(1)` or `first-child` or `last-child` on the class `navLink` it applies the rules to ALL the links, rather than the selected element. I'll post some code below with a jsfiddle to demonstrate my point.

http://jsfiddle.net/rg7fe/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="navItem"><a class="navLink" href="#">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    background: RGB(200, 230, 240);
    border-bottom: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 980px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.navItem {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
 }

.navLink:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);
}

.navLink {
    border-bottom: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.navItem:hover .navLink {
    background: RGB(120, 200, 250);
    color: RGB(255, 255, 255);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply nth-child to  `<li>` not `<a>` which are always  first, last and number one child in `<li>` .

```
.navItem:first-child a{
    border-left: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);
}

.navItem a{
    border-bottom: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.navItem:first-child .navLink {
    border-left: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);
}
```

use it. 
The problem with your method is that .navLink:first-child is calculating first child relative to .navItems which are all items. Hope you got the point.